# Narrow type of any based on string parameter?

Tags: typescript

`tgmlDoc.createElement(tagName)` returns objects of type `any`. I want to narrow the return type in the function below to make life easier for the rest of my code. How can I achieve that? You can see my attempt below. Unfortunately the return type is `TgmlTgml | TgmlLayer | null` regardless of the tagName passed to the function, when I would want it to be `TgmlTgml | null` if tagName tgml is passed and `tgmlLayer | null` if tagName layer is passed.

```
export function createElementIfAllowed(tagName: string, parent: TgmlDocument | TgmlElement) {
  if (!allowedInParent(tagName, parent)) {
    return null;
  }
  const tgmlDoc = parent.ownerDocument || parent;
  const child = tgmlDoc.createElement(tagName);
  // Type narrowing from any
  if (child instanceof TgmlTgml) {
    return child;
  } else if (child instanceof TgmlLayer) {
    return child;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`TGML Element with tagname ${tagName} not allowed`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with function overloading, with one more narrow signature for each string value.

Checking instanceof is optional, since it is okey to narrow any to other types.

```
export function createElementIfAllowed(tagName: "Tgml", parent: TgmlDocument | TgmlElement): TgmlTgml | null;
export function createElementIfAllowed(tagName: "Layer", parent: TgmlDocument | TgmlElement): TgmlLayer | null;
export function createElementIfAllowed(tagName: string, parent: TgmlDocument | TgmlElement): TgmlElement | null {
  if (!allowedInParent(tagName, parent)) {
    return null;
  }
  const tgmlDoc = parent.ownerDocument || parent;
  const child = tgmlDoc.createElement(tagName);
  if (child instanceof TgmlTgml) {
    return child;
  } else if (child instanceof TgmlLayer) {
    return child;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`TGML Element with tagname ${tagName} not allowed`);
  }
}

function isTgmlDocument(val: any): val is TgmlDocument {
  return val instanceof TgmlDocument;
}
```